# Удаленное подключение к mysql

Tags: mysql

На ПК стоит VMware, на ней CentOS 6.5, nginx, php-fpm, mysql (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73), не могу подключиться с хоста к БД через sql менеджер (dbForge)

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:mysql state ESTABLISHED
```

/etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address=192.168.1.5
port=3306

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Давал права пользователю, через которого пытаюсь попасть на ВМ с хоста. Сеть вроде правильно настроена - веб сервер работает как надо. В чем проблема?

Comment: а ошибка какая ? попробуйте  просто cmdline клиентом mysql.

Comment: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'developer.local' (10061):

Server did not respond within the specified timeout interval

developer.local - есть в hosts

Comment: через bash все работает

Comment: через bash на хосте ? ну странно, а этот dbforge вообще по сети умеет работать ? вообще у вас REJECT стоит раньше accept для mysql

Comment: ОС на хосте - windows 7 я имел ввиду через bash с гостевой

Comment: Проблема однозначно в правилах iptables - если сервис отключить, то все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил порядок прав для iptables следующим образом:

/etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Aug 12 13:21:28 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [147:21512]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited  
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 12 13:21:28 2014
```

Заработало. Оказывается, ограничивающие права должны применяться в последнюю очередь - не знал.